# How to setup header search paths for swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

How to setup header search paths for swift classes?

This swift class which is not in project, and I want to import it.

Can it be set like OC in header search paths?

Comment: If it is just swift classes that you want to add to your project, then go to your destination project and `File > Add files` and include the swift files, you can copy them (check box) to your project folder and ensure they are added to the target (check box). Please mention if the swift files are part of a different project and you don't want to copy them

Comment: If you want to add frameworks please mention it in the question, the steps would be different for frameworks

Comment: I do not want add the swift files to framework, but I want import them by setup build settings like 'Header Search Paths', then the project can build successfully.